# Yii2 как с помощью ActiveForm не создавать новый элемент, а обновить?

Tags: yii2, form, update

Yii2 как с помощью ActiveForm не создавать новый элемент, а обновить?

Форма:

```
<?$form = ActiveForm::begin($config);?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'save_images_post')->checkbox()?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'folder_save_images_post')->textInput()?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'save_backups')->checkbox()?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'folder_save_backups')->textInput()?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'path_backups')->textInput()?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'token_yandex_disk')->textInput()?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'id_yandex_disk')->textInput()?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'password_yandex_disk')->textInput()?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'access_to_more_yandex_disk_link')->checkbox()?>
<?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', $status), 'btn btn-success')?>
<?php ActiveForm::end();?>
```

У меня обновление идет в зависимости есть ли элемент или нет. Если есть то обновляется. Это все происходит на странице index.

Вот контроллер -

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new ApiYandexDiskSettings;
        $status = 'update';
        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){
        $model->save(false);
    }
    $firstEl = ApiYandexDiskSettings::find()->one();
    if(empty($firstEl)){
    $status = 'create';
    }else{
        $status = 'update';
    }
        return $this->render('index', array('status' => $status, 'model' =>           
$firstEl));
    }
}
```

Пробую обновить с помощью update() но он возвращает false

```
if(Yii::$app->request->get('status','update')){
    $model->update();
}else{
    $model->save(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Все дело в реализации ApiYandexDiskSettings, если это просто ActiveRecord:

Судя по коду, у вас в базе предполагается только одна запись в базе для этого объекта.
можно поступить так

```
$model = ApiYandexDiskSettings::find()->one();
if (!$model) {
   $model = new ApiYandexDiskSettings();
}
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())
   && $model->save();
return $this->render('index', array('status' => $model->isNewRecord, 'model' =>           
$model));
```